# Proving that the stalk of the sheaf of homomorphisms of a module of finite presentation is isomorphic to the module of homomorphism of stalk

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quasicoherent-sheaves

Consider $\mathscr{F}$ to be a module of finite presentation over a ringed space $X$. I want to prove that, for any sheaf of modules $\mathscr{G}$ and $x \in X$, the canonical morphism $\mathscr{H}om(\mathscr{F}, \mathscr{G})_x \to \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_{X,x}}(\mathscr{F}_x, \mathscr{G}_x)$ is iso. To do so, I am following Görtz-Wedhorn's book, proposition 7.27. In the book, they consider two contravariant functors which they define by:
$$\mathcal{F}: \mathscr{F} \mapsto \mathscr{H}om(\mathscr{F}, \mathscr{G})_x$$
$$\mathcal{F}': \mathscr{F} \mapsto \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_{X, x}}(\mathscr{F}_x, \mathscr{G}_x)$$

Now, I am somewhat confused as to what this contravariant functor mean. Is $\mathcal{F}$
meant to be the functor $\mathscr{H}om(\mathscr{F}, -)_x$, and $\mathcal{F}'$ the functor $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_{X, x}}(\mathscr{F}_x, -_x)$? If so, how are these functors contravariant?

Comment: Fix $\mathcal{G}$ (not $\mathcal{F}$) and put the blank on the *left* side.

Comment: So, as $\mathscr{F}$ is the fixed sheaf, the correct functors would be $\mathscr{H}om(-, \mathscr{F})_x$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{O}_{X, x}}(-_x, \mathscr{F}_x)$?

Comment: No - did you skip the part of the comment where I said to fix $\mathscr{G}$ and not $\mathscr{F}$? The functors are $\mathscr{H}om(-,\mathscr{G})_x$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}(-_x,\mathscr{G}_x)$. It's literally just replacing "$\mathscr{F}$" with "$-$" everywhere it appears.

Comment: If I fix $\mathscr{G}$, then I would have to restrict the functor to the category of sheaves of finite presentation, right? I am confused because I thought that the fixed sheaf should be of finite presentation (and $\mathscr{G}$, as written in the question, is an arbitrary sheaf).

Comment: There is no need to restrict your functors to the subcategory of sheaves of finite presentation - you're trying to prove something when the input is in there, but the functors are defined in general. When I say "fix", I mean "treat as constant" - it's exactly like analyzing a function $(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)$ by looking at the function restricted to the line $y=y_0$ by looking at $x\mapsto f(x,y_0)$.